# BXslider.js is broken when I combine it with Jquery.smoothState.js. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-frontend

I've made a homepage with a fullscreen-image slider using [BXslider.js](http://bxslider.com/). Every single image in the slider has a caption text with a anchor link. 
After hitting the anchor link you will move to a single detailpage. A transition appears if you move from home to a detailpage. This is basicallly the same as the demo on [jquery.smoothstate.js](http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/) page.

I encounter one problem, BXslider is broken after including the jquery.smoothstate javascript. Every time you hit the arrow button prev or next in the BXslider the slider itself overwrites itself and duplicates prev/next buttons and images will dissapear. In firebug I do not get any warning or errors. This makes it hard to debug. Hopefully someone can help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Below you'll find the code i've written for my bxslider.js/smootstate website.

**Code for homepage**

```
        <div id="main" class="m-scene">
            <div class="scene-element scene-element--fadeinup">
            <section id="banner">
                <div class="inner">

                    <div id="box">
                        <div class="relative-box">
                            <div class="logo"></div>
                            <h2>Client-name</h2>
                            <div id="captions">
                                <p>&#34; This is a caption &#34;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="/generic.html" class="more">To genericpage</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="bxslider">
                      <li style="background-image: url('/images/pic1.jpg');"></li>
                      <li style="background-image: url('/images/pic2.jpg');"></li>
                      <li style="background-image: url('/images/pic3');"></li>
                      <li style="background-image: url('/images/pic4.jpg');"></li>
                      <li style="background-image: url('/images/pic5.jpg');"></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**Generic html/css selectors**

I'm using generic html/selectors for the jquery.smootstate.js. Below html is identical for home & detailpage.

```
  <div id="main" class="m-scene">
        <div class="scene-element scene-element--fadeinup">
```

**css3 transitions**

the scene-element & scene-element--fadeinup selectors are used for the css3 page animations.

```
@keyframes fadeInUp{
    0%{opacity:0; transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);}
    100%{opacity:1;transform:none;}
}

.m-scene .scene-element{
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    animtation-fill-mode: both;
}

.m-scene .scene-element--fadeinup {animation-name:fadeInUp;}

.m-scene.is-exiting .scene-element {animation-direction: alternate-reverse;}
```

The javascript for jquery.smoothstate.js

```
        (function($) {
          'use strict';
          var $body = $('html, body'),
              content = $('#smooth').smoothState({
                // Runs when a link has been activated
                onStart: {
                  duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
                  render: function (url, $container) {
                    // toggleAnimationClass() is a public method
                    // for restarting css animations with a class
                    content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');
                    // Scroll user to the top
                    $body.animate({
                      scrollTop: 0
                    });
                  }
                }
              }).data('smoothState');
              //.data('smoothState') makes public methods available
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think I fixed the issue by adding:                                                  $.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

Comment: Why dont you self answer this question and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Learn from my mistakes

**1.Don't do DIY namespaces in jquery.smoothstate**

I've used `#smooth` instead of `#main` as the container `<div>`. My jquery function was trying to call jquery.smoothstate but that won't work because `#main` is used as the identifier in the jquery.smoothstate.js library.

**2.Define anchors instead of making every link part of smoothstate**

After I fixed the above mistake another issue came across. I'm using bxslider in my source. Everytime I pressed the arrow next or prev in the BXslider a new duplicate of the slider appears above the original slider.

I've fixed this by defining an option anchor. This is part of jquery.smoothstate. This will exclude all other anchors.

**3.toggleAnimationClass is deprecated**

Use instead of toggleAnimationClass functioncall restartCSSAnimations();

add temporary class 'is-exited' with addClass()

*This is the full working source:*

```
    (function($) {

      'use strict';

          content = $('#main').smoothState({
            // Runs when a link has been activated
            prefetch: true,
            pageCacheSize: 4,
            anchors: 'link',
            onStart: {
              duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
              render: function (url, $container) {

                //add temporary class #main
                $('#main').addClass('is-exited');

                // for restarting css animations with a class
                content.restartCSSAnimations();

              }
            }
          }).data('smoothState');
    })(jQuery);
```